# Generate matching attribute values with php?

Tags: php, html

This is a script I'm working on, which displays a CSV file as an HTML table. In the HTML table I have a hidden row which, using a jquery script that isn't displayed here, can be toggled to display or hide via a button.

My php script generates the HTML table dynamically, so I'm wondering how can I dynamically generate two matching values for #REPLACEME?

Let's say my CSV file has 20 rows, that means the HTML table will also have 20 rows, and I therefore need 20 unique pairs of values for #REPLACEME.

```
 echo('<tr>');
        echo('<td>
            <button class="toggler" data-prod-cat="#REPLACEME">Vote</button>
        </td>');
        echo('</tr>');
        echo('<tr class="cat#REPLACEME hidden">');
        echo('</tr>')
```

---

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("example.csv", "r");
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    $color = $data[3];
    $options = $data[5];
    echo('<table>');
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $color = $data[3];
        $options = $data[5];
        //generate HTML
        echo('<tr data-color="' . $color . '" data-options="' . $options . '">');
        foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {
            echo('<td>');
            echo htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES);
            echo('</td>');
        }

        echo('</tr>');
        echo('<tr>');
        echo('<td>
            <button class="toggler" data-prod-cat="#REPLACEME">Vote</button>
        </td>');
        echo('</tr>');
        echo('<tr class="cat#REPLACEME hidden">');
        echo('</tr>')
    }

    echo("</table>");
    fclose($handle);
    ?>
```

Comment: why would you need a unique one, you can use classes to toggle those

Comment: Using a class instead of a unique value would toggle all the hidden rows when any of the buttons are clicked, no?

I need each specific button to toggle a specific row, therefore they have to have a matching value.

Comment: are you using jquery? no you would only toggle the one you clicked but you bind that event on every button

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with an example of my jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/zoo6mvso/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple incrementing value will work fine:

```
$i = 1;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    // use $i as a basis for your ID, perhaps
    $cssId = 'row-'.$i;

    $i++;
}
```